# std vector size keep ground Although i insert in the same indexs

Tags: c++, stdvector

Something wired i see here with std vector 
I have 
variable that its value is dynamically changes but always under 20 
dynamicSizeToInsert in the example. 
why the vector size keeps growing ?

```
std::vector<int> v;
//sometimes its 5 sometimes it is 10 sometimes it is N < 20 
int dynamicSizeToInsert = 5 
int c = 0;  
for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != 100; i++) {
     if(c == dynamicSizeToInsert )
     {
        c = 0;
     }
     v.insert(v.begin() + c, c);
     c++;

     printf("%d",v.size())  //THIS THINK KEEP growing although i only using vector indexes 0 to  4  allways
}
```

i want to keep my vector side 5 elements big 
and that new value will run over other value in the same index .

Comment: Reread the description of what vector::insert does.

Comment: o crap it just keep it growing .. thanks , what is the best alternative ?

Comment: @user63898 if you just want to overwrite existing entries, use the god old access `operator[]`, i.e. `v[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), as the name suggests, *inserts* elements at the specified position.

When `c == dynamicSizeToInsert`, `c` is set to `0`. So now, `v.size() == 5`. Now this lines executes:

```
v.insert(v.begin() + c, c);
```

This will insert `0` at posistion `v.begin() + 0`, which is position `0` and it will offset every other element (it will *not* replace the element at position `0`), and so the vector keeps growing.

---

Instead of using `insert`, use `operator[]`:

```
//So that 'v' is the right size
v.resize(dynamicSizeToInsert);

for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != 100; i++) {
     if(c == dynamicSizeToInsert )
     {
        c = 0;
     }

     v[i] = c; //Sets current index to 'c'
     c++;
}
```

Comment: The resize at first is very important!

Comment: @user63898 Yeah, or you will try to access non-allocated memory :)

Answer (score 1):

std::vector::insert inserts a new member into the array at the index you specify, and moving the other elements forward or even reallocating the array once it reaches capacity(a relatively expensive operation)

> The vector is extended by inserting new elements before the element at
>   the specified position, effectively increasing the container size by
>   the number of elements inserted.
>
> This causes an automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space
>   if -and only if- the new vector size surpasses the current vector
>   capacity.
>   (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/)

As quoted above, the vector is extended with every insert operation.
to get the behaviour you want you need to use the [] operator like so:

```
v[i] = some_new_value;
```

this way a new element is never added, its only the value of the ith element that is changed.

Answer (score 1):

[insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) doesn't replace element, rather it inserts element at given location and shifts all the right elements to one position right. That's why your vector size is growing.

If you want to replace an existing index then you can use [operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at). However, keep in mind that the index must be between `0 - size() - 1` in order to use `operator[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int dynamicSizeToInsert = 5;
std::vector<int> v(dynamicSizeToInsert);
int c = 0;  
for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i !=100; i++) 
{
     v.at(i%dynamicSizeToInsert) = (dynamicSizeToInsert == c?c = 0,c ++: c ++);

     printf("%d",v.size());
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not recommended, it would be better to include some explanation.